# Angular, Ionic Swappable Grid does not swap the right elements

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

On the following project: https://github.com/pc-magas/faster

I generate a grid like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="(i,row) in grid.value" class="row">
    <div  ng-repeat="(j,item) in row" class="col">
      <img on-swipe-up="swipeup({{i}},{{j}})" on-swipe-down="swipeDown({{i}},{{j}})" on-swipe-left="swipeLeft({{i}},{{j}})" on-swipe-right="swipeRight({{i}},{{j}})" src="{{item.icon}}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And His is the code on my controller:

```
.controller('Game',function($scope,$state,$ionicModal,Game,MenuItem)
{

  /*###################### Modal Area ######################*/
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('gameOverModal.html',
  {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  })
  .then(function(modal)
  {
    $scope.gameOverModal = modal;
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function()
  {
    $scope.gameOverModal.remove();
  });

  $scope.closeGameOverModal=function()
  {
    $scope.gameOverModal.hide();
    $state.go("menu");
  }
  /*###############################################################*/

  /*################### Controller Initialization ####################*/
  var GameItem=Game.item;
  var GameClass=Game.game;
  /*##################### End Controller Initialization ##############*/

  /**
  *Function That does all the dirty job for initialization
  */
  var init_game=function()
  {
    console.log(Game.current_game);
    if(typeof Game.current_game === 'undefined' || Game.current_game === null)
    {
      /**
      *Items for the Game
      */
      var items=[
                  new GameItem('img/icon1.jpg','img/icon1.jpg','img/icon1.jpg','trolley'),
                  new GameItem('img/icon2.jpg','img/icon2.jpg','img/icon2.jpg','metro'),
                  new GameItem('img/icon3.jpg','img/icon3.jpg','img/icon3.jpg','bus'),
                  new GameItem('img/icon4.jpg','img/icon4.jpg','img/icon4.jpg','tram'),
                ];

      /**
      *Callbacks for Game
      */
      var callbacks={
                      'pause':function(time)
                      {
                        console.log("Game Paused");
                        $state.go('menu');
                      },
                      'afterInit':function(game)
                      {
                        MenuItem.items.play.name_="Continue Game";
                        MenuItem.items.play.clickFunction=function()
                        {
                          console.log("clicked");
                          $state.go('game');
                          Game.current_game.play();//Do not comment unlsess game will not resume
                        };

                        /*Making An Option For saving*/
                        var saveItem=new MenuItem.MenuItem("Save Game",'regular-btn',"",false,function()
                        {
                          game.save();
                        });
                        //Add on the top an Option to save the game
                        MenuItem.items.others.unshift(saveItem);
                        console.log(MenuItem.items.others);
                      },
                      'over':function()
                      {
                        ionic.EventController.trigger('gameOver',{});
                      }
                    };

      Game.current_game=new GameClass(items,60,5,5,callbacks,$scope);
      Game.current_game.init();
    }
    else // We may need to go to another page and return Therefore we must need a way to resume
    {
      console.log("Here resuming the game");
      Game.current_game.play();
    }
    $scope.timer = Game.current_game.timer;
    $scope.points=Game.current_game.getScore();
    $scope.grid=Game.current_game.grid;

    /*Functions that do all the swipe*/
    $scope.swipeup=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'up');
      $scope.grid=Game.current_game.grid;
    };

    $scope.swipeDown=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'down');
    };

    $scope.swipeLeft=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'left');
    };

    $scope.swipeRight=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'right');
    };
    /*End of: "Functions that do all the swap"*/
  };

  ionic.EventController.on('gameOver',function()
  {
    console.log("GameOver Event");

    MenuItem.items.play.name_="New Game";
    MenuItem.items.others.shift();
    Game.current_game=null;
    $scope.gameOverModal.show();
  });

  init_game();

  $scope.pause=function()
  {
    console.log("Pausing Game");
    Game.current_game.pause();

  }
});
```

As you can See the lines that does the swap are:

```
    /*Functions that do all the swipe*/
    $scope.swipeup=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'up');
      $scope.grid=Game.current_game.grid;
    };

    $scope.swipeDown=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'down');
    };

    $scope.swipeLeft=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'left');
    };

    $scope.swipeRight=function(i,j)
    {
      Game.current_game.swap(i,j,'right');
    };
    /*End of: "Functions that do all the swap"*/
  };
```

And on my service the functions that does the swap is:

```
game.swap=function(i,j,direction)
        {
          console.log("i: "+i,"j: "+j)
          switch(direction)
          {
            case 'up':
              if(i!==0) //Cannot swap first line elements
              {
                console.log("Can swap Up");
                swapAction(i,j,i-1,j);
              }
              break;
            case 'down':
              if(i!==game.grid.value.length-1) //cannot swap last line elements
              {
                console.log("Can swap Down");
                swapAction(i,j,i+1,j);
              }
              break;
            case 'left':
              if(j!==0) //Cannot swap first column elements
              {
                console.log("Can swap Left");
                swapAction(i,j,i,j-1);
              }
              break;
            case 'right':
              if(j!==game.grid.value[i].length-1) //Cannot swap last column elements
              {
                console.log("Can swap Right");
                swapAction(i,j,i,j+1);
              }
              break;
          }
        };

        var swapAction=function(i,j,newi,newj)
        {
          var temp=game.grid.value[i][j];
          game.grid.value[i][j]=game.grid.value[newi][newj];
          game.grid.value[newi][newj]=temp;
        }
```

As I noticed after a few swaps the swapped elements are not the correct one. Eg. If an element is in Position 4,3 and I swap with the element in the position  4,4 then in initially swaps but I cannot swap it back.

And this happend because the {{i}} and {{j}} passed as parameters are not the correct one. Do you have an Idea how on swipe will get the correct {{i}} and {{j}} each time?

One soulution That I thought is what If "baptized" each element with a unique number and look for the posizition of each element on the loop but I think is not the best one performance-wize.

An another solution that I thought is for each swappable object to have an swipe() method but still I will need to find the Object's Coordinates on the grid. Also for that I am not too sure if it is Possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it by doing this:

I chaned the GameItem like that:

```
function GameItem(icon,icon_destroyed,icon_marked,name,unique)
{
    item.unique=(unique)?unique:0;//A unique number for new items

    ...
    item.uniqueId=function()
    {
      return item.name+item.unique;
    }

    ....
    item.clone=function()
    {
      var newClone=new GameItem(item.icon,item.icon_destroyed,item.icon_marked,item.name,item.unique);
      item.unique++;//After a clone refresh the unique number in order the next clones to have new name
      return newClone;
    }
}
```

Also now on the services on Game I set a new method:

```
game.swapById=function(unique,direction)
{
 for(var i=0;i<game.grid.value.length;i++)
 {
  for(var j=0;j<game.grid.value[i].length;j++)
  {
    var item=game.grid.value[i][j];
     console.log(item.uniqueId(),unique);
     if(item.uniqueId()===unique)
     {
       game.swap(i,j,direction);
       return;
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Therefore I look for a uniqie Id ;)

SO my html is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(i,row) in grid.value" class="row">
    <div  ng-repeat="(j,item) in row" class="col">
      <img on-swipe-up="swipeup('{{item.uniqueId()}}')" on-swipe-down="swipeDown('{{item.uniqueId()}}')" on-swipe-left="swipeLeft('{{item.uniqueId()}}')" on-swipe-right="swipeRight('{{item.uniqueId()}}')" src="{{item.icon}}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I call the following methods from the controller:

```
$scope.swipeup=function(unique)
{
  Game.current_game.swapById(unique,'up');
};

$scope.swipeDown=function(unique)
{
 Game.current_game.swapById(unique,'down');
};

$scope.swipeLeft=function(unique)
{
 Game.current_game.swapById(unique,'left');
};

$scope.swipeRight=function(unique)
{
  Game.current_game.swapById(unique,'right');
};
```

I think is a helpfull solution ;)